# File upload not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I have a form (left out action route for berevity)

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input type="file" name="avatarImage" id="avatarImage" />
   <input type='hidden' name='_token' value='{{csrf_token()}}' />
```

When I post and do

```
dd($request);
```

All it shows is my csrf_token.  No file.

Everyone who has had a similar issue seems to have forgotten the multipart/form-data part.  And that fixes their issue.

I have included this, and still can't seem to retrieve files
Even if I just to

```
 dd($_POST) or dd($_FILES)
```

nothing, both empty.

Comment: provide your complete `form structure`, your `routes` and method where you are making `dd($request);`

Comment: @KyleK: have you resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add few properties to form attribute

```
   {{ Form::open(['url' => 'admin/applications/'.$application->id.'/apks', 'method' => 'post',"class"=>"form-horizontal",'files' => true])}}
```

After that you can see the uploaded file

```
dd(Input::all())
```